# How to push Fixed div with another fixed div

Tags: css, html, responsive-design, fixed

How to I push a fixed top div with 100% width, when another fixed right div is supposed to push it from the right side? I am making a collapsible mobile menu. It is toggled by a button on the top fixed div. Right now, the right fixed div overlaps the top fixed div menu button. I want this button to move left on the screen so that it is visible at all times. How do I accomplish this? I have not worked a whole lot with fixed elements in css. Thanks for any help.

**Note: You will only see the menu and menu button I am talking about by resizing your browser window smaller. This menu is designed for a mobile layout.**

Site:

http://dai1.designangler.com/

CSS:

```
#slide-menu {
  margin-right: -250px;
  right: 0;
  top:0;
  width: 250px;
  background: #222;
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: auto;
  z-index: 10001;
  font-family: Roboto,sans-serif;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 100;
  font-size: 1.5em;
}


#push{
  /* This is the div that holds the menu button */
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  padding: 0 1em;
  background: #366982;
  width:100%;
  display:none; 
  z-index: 10000;
}
```

Screenshots to illustrate point:

menu closed: http://prntscr.com/2oaf82

menu open with button being overlapped: http://prntscr.com/2oafv4

Answer (score 0):

You can't. Fixed is fixed. There are other ways though. Here's one:

In your JS that toggles the menu (`$('#push, #close').click(function () {...}`) also toggle a class on your `body` element called `.menu-open`

```
$('body').toggleClass('menu-open');
```

And update your css:

```
.menu-btn {
    float: right;
    margin-right: 2em;
}
.menu-open .menu-btn {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 0;
    margin-left: 2em;
}
```

Comment: `position: fixed` won't float.

Comment: @MarcellFülöp Indeed but after looking at his code, the menu toggle element itself is not fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot "push" a fixed element with any other because it is not relative to any other.

One way to do it taking another approach is to just change css `right: 0` to `left: 0` (or animate if you prefer) of the menu button container. A hint for this is that if you want to swap left and right properties of an element, you will have to give the other (being "removed", but you cannot really remove it) the `auto` value.

You can also have both elements displayed relative to each other in a container element and move that to achieve the effect of menu coming in from the right while the push button slide with it the left.